# Getting error while building org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table_name is not mapped

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting the below error when i try to view the webpage on localhost:8081/getAllCandidates.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Candidate is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3687) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3576) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:572) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at com.example.demo.dao.CandidateDAOImpl.getAllCandidates(CandidateDAOImpl.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.dao.CandidateDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$51c81b45.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.dao.CandidateDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e88a072.getAllCandidates(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.service.CandidateService.getAllCandidates(CandidateService.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.service.CandidateService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6e35df65.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.service.CandidateService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$209fe924.getAllCandidates(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.CandidateController.getAllCandidates(CandidateController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
```

I have followed the answers from SO, but still getting the same error.Please find the below code and suggest me to resolve.

CandidateController

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.demo.model.Candidate;
import com.example.demo.service.CandidateService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class CandidateController {
    @Autowired
    CandidateService candidateService;
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllCandidates", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    
    public String getAllCandidates(Model model) {
 
        List<Candidate> listOfCandidates = candidateService.getAllCandidates();
        model.addAttribute("candidate", new Candidate());
        model.addAttribute("listOfCandidates", listOfCandidates);
        return "candidateDetails";
    }
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String goToHomePage() {
        return "redirect:/getAllCandidates";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getCandidate/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Candidate getCandidateById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return candidateService.getCandidate(id);
    }
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCandidate", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String addCandidate(@ModelAttribute("candidate") Candidate candidate) {  
        if(candidate.getId()==0)
        {
            candidateService.addCandidate(candidate);
        }
        else
        {   
            candidateService.updateCandidate(candidate);
        }
 
        return "redirect:/getAllCandidates";
    }
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateCandidate/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String updateCandidate(@PathVariable("id") int id,Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("candidate", this.candidateService.getCandidate(id));
        model.addAttribute("listOfCandidates", this.candidateService.getAllCandidates());
        return "candidateDetails";
    }
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteCandidate/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String deleteCandidate(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        candidateService.deleteCandidate(id);
        return "redirect:/getAllCandidates";
 
    }   
}
```

CandidateService

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
 
import com.example.demo.dao.CandidateDAO;
import com.example.demo.model.Candidate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("candidateService")
public class CandidateService {
    @Autowired
    
    CandidateDAO candidateDao;
 
    @Transactional
    public List<Candidate> getAllCandidates() {
        return candidateDao.getAllCandidates();
    }
 
    @Transactional
    public Candidate getCandidate(int id) {
        return candidateDao.getCandidate(id);
    }
 
    @Transactional
    public void addCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
        candidateDao.addCandidate(candidate);
    }
 
    @Transactional
    public void updateCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
        candidateDao.updateCandidate(candidate);
 
    }
 
    @Transactional
    public void deleteCandidate(int id) {
        candidateDao.deleteCandidate(id);
    }

}
```

CandidateDAOImpl

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.demo.model.Candidate;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class CandidateDAOImpl implements CandidateDAO{
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }
 
    
    public List<Candidate> getAllCandidates() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Candidate>  candidateList = session.createQuery("from Candidate").list();
        return candidateList;
    }
 
    public Candidate getCandidate(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Candidate candidate = session.get(Candidate.class, id);
        return candidate;
    }
 
    public Candidate addCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(candidate);
        return candidate;
    }
 
    public void updateCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Hibernate.initialize(candidate);
        session.update(candidate);
    }
 
    public void deleteCandidate(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Candidate p = session.load(Candidate.class, new Integer(id));
        if (null != p) {
            session.delete(p);
        }
    }
}
```

CandidateDAO

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.demo.model.Candidate;

public interface CandidateDAO {
    public List<Candidate> getAllCandidates() ;
     
    public Candidate getCandidate(int id) ;
 
    public Candidate addCandidate(Candidate candidate);
 
    public void updateCandidate(Candidate candidate) ;
 
    public void deleteCandidate(int id) ;

    
}
```

Candidate.java

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name="Candidate")
@javax.persistence.Table(name="CANDIDATE")
public class Candidate {
        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        int id;
     
        @Column(name="firstName")
        String firstName; 
        
        @Column(name="lastName")
        String lastName;
        
        @Column(name="dob")
        String dob;
     
        @Column(name="email")
        String email;
        
        @Column(name="degree")
        String degree;
        
        @Column(name="status")
        String status;
     
        public Candidate() {
            super();
        }
        public Candidate(String firstName,String lastName,String dob,String email,String degree,String status) {
            super();
            this.firstName=firstName;
            this.lastName=lastName;
            this.dob=dob;
            this.email=email;
            this.degree=degree;
            this.status=status;
        }
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        public String getDob() {
            return dob;
        }
        public void setDob(String dob) {
            this.dob = dob;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getdegree() {
            return degree;
        }
        public void setdegree(String degree) {
            this.degree = degree;
        }
        public String getstatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void setstatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        
    }
```

HibernateConfiguration

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class HibernateConfiguration {
        @Value("${db.driver}")
        private String DRIVER;
     
        @Value("${db.password}")
        private String PASSWORD;
     
        @Value("${db.url}")
        private String URL;
     
        @Value("${db.username}")
        private String USERNAME;
     
        @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
        private String DIALECT;
     
        @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
        private String SHOW_SQL;
     
        @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
        private String HBM2DDL_AUTO;
     
        @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
        private String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;
     
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER);
            dataSource.setUrl(URL);
            dataSource.setUsername(USERNAME);
            dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
            return dataSource;
        }
     
        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
            Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", DIALECT);
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", SHOW_SQL);
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HBM2DDL_AUTO);
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
     
            return sessionFactory;
        }
     
        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }   
    }
```

DemoApplication

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo"})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootHibernateExample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- For JSP compilation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.threeten/threetenbp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
#server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
#spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
server.port=8081
logging.level=DEBUG
# Database
db.driver: org.postgresql.Driver
db.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
db.username: test
db.password: test
 
# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create
entitymanager.packagesToScan: org
 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CANDIDATE;

CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL,
dob DATE DEFAULT NULL,
email VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE,
degree VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL,
status VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller:

- Remove the empty line between @RequestMapping and getAllCandidates method.
- You can also change the @RequestMapping to @GetMapping, if you want.

In your DAOImpl:

- Change the query in getAllCandidates method as like below structure

  String sql = "SELECT * FROM CANDIDATE";
  SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
  query.addEntity(Candidate.class);
  List results = query.list();

Comment: @PBKN....After adding your changes i am getting ```Unknown entity: com.example.demo.model.Candidate; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.example.demo.model.Candidate```

Comment: `@Entity(name="Candidate")` to `@Entity`

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties `entitymanager.packagesToScan` should be `com.example.demo.model`

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Candidate> getAllCandidates() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Candidate>  candidateList = session.createQuery("from Candidate").list();
    return candidateList;
}
```

=>

```
return session.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Candidate c", Candidate.class).getResultList();
```